# Get Count From UserID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I need a way of getting a unique count of `ek` that is associated with each `userid`

My desired output is:

```
74123    3
```

But I can not seem to get the syntax for the Distinct count accurate.  I can only get it to return the TOTAL count which is not what I am after.

DDL

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[___________Purple](
    [userid] [int] NULL,
    [ek] [char](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Black                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Black                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Black                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Black                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Black                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Black                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Green                                                                                               ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Pink                                                                                                ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Pink                                                                                                ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Pink                                                                                                ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Pink                                                                                                ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Pink                                                                                                ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Pink                                                                                                ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Pink                                                                                                ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[___________Purple] ([userid], [ek]) VALUES (71423, N'Pink                                                                                                ')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(DISTINCT ek) AS total_ek
FROM dbo.[___________Purple]
GROUP BY userid;
```

The results:

[image]

And for folks like me who were confused about how the question found 3 different ek's - make sure to scroll down in his epic long DDL query.

Comment: I NEVER knew you could embed a Distinct inside a count like that!  Excellent!

Comment: I'm chock full of bad ideas.